# Text does not copy to clipboard android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to copy an URL to clipboard onClickListener, The URL does not show up on clipboard here is my code

```
private static void copyToClipboard(Context context) {
    try {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("https://lynxkik.org", (CharSequence) context);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Link Copied To Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html#newPlainText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Assuming the text you want to copy is `https://lynxkik.org`, the call should be:

```
android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Label here", "https://lynxkik.org");
```

Comment: The label is simply a bit of text shown to the user that allows them to recognise the copied text. Your app name or something unique to your app would suffice

Comment: Presumably, it is not throwing an exception anymore. Move the call to `toast` outside the catch block and put something useful like `e.printStackTrace()` inside the catch block instead